# How can I get the Html elements in this code to behave as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vuejs3

I have this laravel app where I converted the blade files to vue.js files. I got this to work except that I couldn't get the navigation section on the vue file to display.

This is the code of the blade layout file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="SmartWealth helps you take charge of your financial well being by making it easy to save and invest towards meeting your life-stage goals.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="smartwealth,finance,personal finance,fintech,investment,save,stock market">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="kI2nwnIamrPbcAFSVICnnFmdJQxOZc2b7jvftnChRME" />


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}">

    <title>SmartWealth: {{ $title }}</title>
  </head>
    <body>
    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light t-navbar fixed-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('index') }}"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo.svg') }}" class="logo"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item {{ Request::is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('index') }}">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item {{ Request::is('howitworks') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('howitworks') }}">How It Works</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://app.smartwealthadvisors.com/getstarted">Risk Assessment</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item {{ Request::is('resources') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('resources') }}">Resources</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://app.smartwealthadvisors.com">Login</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    
    <footer class="bg-footer">
          <div class="container ptop-m pbtm-s">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6  ptop-s">
                <img src="img/logo-g.svg" style="height: 5rem;">
                <div class="ptop-s">
                  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Smartwealthng/"><span class="social"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></span></a>
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/smartwealthng"><span class="social"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></span></a>
                  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/smartwealthng/"><span class="social"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></span></a>
                  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/smartwealth-advisors"><span class="social"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></span></a>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 ptop-s">
                <h4>Company</h4>
                  <li><a href="{{ route('about') }}">About SmartWealth</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{{ route('investmentapproach') }}">Investment Approach</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{{ route('purposefulcapitalism') }}">Purposeful Capitalism</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{{ route('pricing') }}">Pricing</a></li>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 ptop-s">
                <h4>Legal</h4>
                  <li><a href="{{ route('privacy') }}">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{{ route('terms') }}">Terms of Service</a></li>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 ptop-s">
                <h4>Contact</h4>
                  <li>Plot 19B, Block 3, Crospil Estate, Anansa Road, Calabar, Cross River State.</li>
                  <li>+234 8033587748</li>
                  <p>connect@smartwealthadvisors.com</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <h6>Disclosure</h6>
          <p>
              SmartWealth is subject to an Investment Advisory Agreement 
              (IAA) and designed primarily for long-term investors. Investing involve risks, including the possible loss of your capital. You should 
              not enter into any transactions unless you have fully understood all such risks and have independently determined that such 
              transactions are appropriate for you. Any discussion of the risks contained herein with respect to any security should not be 
              considered to be a disclosure of all risks or complete discussion of the risks which are mentioned. Past performance does not 
              guarantee future returns. Historical and expected returns projections are provided for informational and illustrative purposes 
              and may not reflect actual future performances.
          </p>
          <p>
              SmartWealth is a web-based service designed to assist clients in achieving discrete financial goals. It is not intended to 
              provide comprehensive tax advice or financial planning with respect to every aspect of a client's financial situation and do not 
              incorporate specific investments that clients hold elsewhere. You should not construe any of the material contained herein as 
              comprehensive business, hedging, legal, regulatory, tax, or accounting advice and you may want to consult your business advisor, 
              attorney, and tax and accounting advisors concerning any such contemplated transactions. See Terms of Service for full disclosures.
          </p>
          <p class="ptop-m">
            &copy; Ifriqiya Limited <?php echo date('Y') ?>. All rights reserved.
          </p>
          </div>
        </footer>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

It gives this result [image: Output of blade layout]

It works for mobile also [image: Output on mobile]

This the code after I converted to vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Head :title="title" />
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light t-navbar fixed-top">
      <Link class="navbar-brand" :href="route('welcome')">
        <img src="img/logo.svg" class="logo" />
      </Link>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <Link
              class="nav-link"
              :href="route('welcome')"
              :class="{ active: $page.url === '/' }"
              >Home</Link
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <Link
              class="nav-link"
              :href="route('howitworks')"
              :class="{ active: $page.url === '/howitworks' }"
              >How It Works</Link
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <Link class="nav-link" :href="route('register')">Register</Link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <Link
              class="nav-link"
              :href="route('resources')"
              :class="{ active: $page.url === '/resources' }"
              >Resources</Link
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <Link class="nav-link" :href="route('login')">Login</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <main>
      <slot></slot>
    </main>

    <!-- Page Footer -->
    <footer class="bg-footer">
      <div class="container ptop-m pbtm-s">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 ptop-s">
            <img src="img/logo-g.svg" style="height: 5rem" />
            <div class="ptop-s">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Smartwealthng/"
                ><span class="social"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></span
              ></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/smartwealthng"
                ><span class="social"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></span
              ></a>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/smartwealthng/"
                ><span class="social"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></span
              ></a>
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/smartwealth-advisors"
                ><span class="social"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></span
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 ptop-s">
            <h4>Company</h4>
            <li>
              <Link :href="route('about')">About SmartWealth</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link :href="route('investmentapproach')">Investment Approach</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link :href="route('purposefulcapitalism')">Purposeful Capitalism</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link :href="route('pricing')">Pricing</Link>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 ptop-s">
            <h4>Legal</h4>
            <li>
              <Link :href="route('policy')">Privacy Policy</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link :href="route('terms')">Terms of Service</Link>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 ptop-s">
            <h4>Contact</h4>
            <li>
              Plot 19B, Block 3, Crospil Estate, Anansa Road, Calabar, Cross River State.
            </li>
            <li>+234 8033587748</li>
            <p>connect@smartwealthadvisors.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <h6>Disclosure</h6>
        <p>
          SmartWealth is subject to an Investment Advisory Agreement (IAA) and designed
          primarily for long-term investors. Investing involve risks, including the
          possible loss of your capital. You should not enter into any transactions unless
          you have fully understood all such risks and have independently determined that
          such transactions are appropriate for you. Any discussion of the risks contained
          herein with respect to any security should not be considered to be a disclosure
          of all risks or complete discussion of the risks which are mentioned. Past
          performance does not guarantee future returns. Historical and expected returns
          projections are provided for informational and illustrative purposes and may not
          reflect actual future performances.
        </p>
        <p>
          SmartWealth is a web-based service designed to assist clients in achieving
          discrete financial goals. It is not intended to provide comprehensive tax advice
          or financial planning with respect to every aspect of a client's financial
          situation and do not incorporate specific investments that clients hold
          elsewhere. You should not construe any of the material contained herein as
          comprehensive business, hedging, legal, regulatory, tax, or accounting advice
          and you may want to consult your business advisor, attorney, and tax and
          accounting advisors concerning any such contemplated transactions. See Terms of
          Service for full disclosures.
        </p>
        <p class="ptop-m">
          &copy; Ifriqiya Limited {{ currentYear }}. All rights reserved.
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Head, Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3"
import { computed, onMounted } from "vue"
import "/public/css/styles.css"

defineProps({
  title: String,
  currentYear: String
})

const currentYear = computed(() => {
  return new Date().getFullYear()
})

const scripts = [
  "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js",
  "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]

onMounted(() => {
  let index = 0
  function loadNextScript() {
    if (index >= scripts.length) return

    let script = scripts[index]
    let tag = document.createElement("script")
    tag.setAttribute("src", script)
    tag.setAttribute("async", true)
    tag.onload = loadNextScript
    document.head.appendChild(tag)

    index++
  }
  loadNextScript()
})
</script>

<style scoped>
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700|Quicksand:400";
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
#navbarNavDropdown li a.active {
  color: #3869d4;
}
</style>
```

Page works except the navigation section which is blank: [image: Output of vue file]

It doesn't work on mobile either [image: Output for mobile-vue]

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's dev console, and can you include them in your question if so?

Comment: What is `loadNextScript()` suppose to do? It seems like you intend to loop over the `scripts` array but it only loads the first script.

Comment: Hi, @yoduh, there are no errors at all.

Comment: @johan, loadNextScript() works just fine. What I have there ensures that the scripts are loaded sequentially so jquery loads before the bootstrap.

Comment: @Adefowowe well the code you posted `loadNextScript()` will only load jQuery because it is only called once. You should put these as script tags in your index.html header. Why are you loading jQuery and bootstrap anyway? In vue you don't need jQuery and there is a vue implementation for bootstrap: https://bootstrap-vue.org/

Comment: @johan, loadNextScript proceeds until the index length is reached and this part of the function `tag.onload = loadNextScript` calls it again, are you saying it doesn't? I have these scripts here because I only use them for the web pages and putting them in my app entry point interferes with other sections. I inherited the jquery and bootstrap from a design agency I no longer have access to. I'll check out your link. Thanks